# Python перебор словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть 1 словарь и его перебор:

```
cmd = (c for c,v in questions_dict.items() for x in v if x in command)
print(cmd)
```

Результат: < generator object sel_question.. at 0x0000019FB2F9D2C8>

Как мне это исправить? Чтобы переменная cmd хранила значение ключа. 
Вот код не в одну строку, который делает все правильно:

```
for c,v in questions_dict.items():
    for x in v:
        if x in command:
            similarities(c, command)
        else:
            continue
```

Пример списка:

```
questions_dict = {
    'a': ('a1', 'a2', 'a3'),
    'b': ('b1', 'b2', 'b3'),
    'c': ('c1', 'c2', 'c3'),
    'd': ('d1', 'd2', 'd3'),
    'e': ('e1', 'e2', 'e3'),
    'f': ('f1', 'f2', 'f3'),
    'g': ('g1', 'g2', 'g3'),
}
```

Comment: замените `c = (...)` --> `c = [...]` ;)

Comment: По-моему вам нужен `set()`, он как раз вам сделает пересечение двух множеств. @MaxU, что думаете?

Comment: @0andriy, да, похоже достаточно будет сделать пересечение множеств - `command` и `questions_dict.keys()` Если `command` - это коллекция, а не строка

Comment: @MLedIum, приведите в вопросе примеры данных для `questions_dict` и для `command` и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: @MaxU, command - строка. Заменил (...) на [...][0] и все работает как надо. Если не поставить [0] то выводится список из 1 элемента, который мне нужен для сравнения

Comment: Вы можете разбить строку и использовать `set()`: `set(...keys(), command.split())`, как-то так.